Mint function is failing with Status: "Unfinalized (Safe)"everytime, i am trying to mint the contract
function mint() public {
    uint256 newItemId = _nextTokenId;
    require(newItemId < MAX_SUPPLY, "All tokens have already been minted");
    _nextTokenId++; // Increment after minting
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, getTokenURI(newItemId));
    }

it is working fine on remix.
only when i try to write contract after verifying it is throwing issue.
here is the complete solidity file.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Base64.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract PokemonInfoContract is ERC721URIStorage {
    struct PokemonInfo {
        string name;
        string ability;
        string moves;
        string weight;
        string height;
    }

    using Strings for uint256;

    uint256 private _nextTokenId;

    uint256 public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 100000;

    PokemonInfo[] public pokemonList;

    constructor() ERC721("Pokemon Generate", "RPG") {}

    function generateCharacter(
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public view returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory svg = abi.encodePacked(
            '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 350 350">',
            "<style>.base {font-family: serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; }</style>",
            '<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />',
            '<text x="50%" y="20%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">'
            "Name:",
            getName(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="40%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">'
            "Ability:",
            getAbility(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="60%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">',
            "Moves:",
            getMoves(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="80%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">',
            "Height:",
            getHeight(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="90%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">',
            "Weight:",
            getWeight(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            "</svg>"
        );
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:image/svg+xml;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(svg)
                )
            );
    }

    function getName(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.name;
    }

    function getAbility(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.ability;
    }

    function getMoves(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.moves;
    }

    function getHeight(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.height;
    }

    function getWeight(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.weight;
    }

    function getTokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            "{",
            '"name": "Generate Random Pokemon #',
            tokenId.toString(),
            '",',
            '"description": "Generate Random Pokemon",',
            '"image": "',
            generateCharacter(tokenId),
            '"',
            "}"
        );
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:application/json;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(dataURI)
                )
            );
    }

    function mint() public {
    uint256 newItemId = _nextTokenId;
    require(newItemId < MAX_SUPPLY, "All tokens have already been minted");
    _nextTokenId++; // Increment after minting
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, getTokenURI(newItemId));
    }

    function generatePokeMon(
        string calldata name,
        string calldata height,
        string calldata weight,
        string calldata moves,
        string calldata ability
    ) public returns (string memory) {
        uint256 newItemId = _nextTokenId;
        require(newItemId < MAX_SUPPLY, "All tokens have already been minted");
        
        pokemonList.push(PokemonInfo(name, ability, height, weight, moves));

        _nextTokenId++;
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, getTokenURI(newItemId));
        return (getTokenURI(newItemId));
    }
}

Help me out here, i tried using AI tools however to no avail.

You've added the minting logic twice: once in the mint function and again in the generatePokeMon function. As a result, the _nextTokenId and newItemId are both being incremented twice, causing a failure or revert when getTokenURI(newItemId) is called.
To fix this, make your mint function private and call it from within the generatePokeMon function. Then, remove the minting logic from the generatePokeMon function and retain only the code for pushing to the pokemonList array.
Now, when you call the generatePokeMon function, it'll generate the pokemon character and mint the corresponding NFT.
So, your revised contract code would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Base64.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract PokemonInfoContract is ERC721URIStorage {
    struct PokemonInfo {
        string name;
        string ability;
        string moves;
        string weight;
        string height;
    }

    using Strings for uint256;

    uint256 private _nextTokenId;

    uint256 public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 100000;

    PokemonInfo[] public pokemonList;

    constructor() ERC721("Pokemon Generate", "RPG") {}

    function generateCharacter(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        returns (string memory)
    {
        bytes memory svg = abi.encodePacked(
            '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 350 350">',
            "<style>.base {font-family: serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; }</style>",
            '<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />',
            '<text x="50%" y="20%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">'
            "Name:",
            getName(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="40%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">'
            "Ability:",
            getAbility(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="60%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">',
            "Moves:",
            getMoves(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="80%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">',
            "Height:",
            getHeight(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            '<text x="50%" y="90%" class="base" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" fill="#ff6ac2">',
            "Weight:",
            getWeight(tokenId),
            "</text>",
            "</svg>"
        );
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:image/svg+xml;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(svg)
                )
            );
    }

    function getName(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.name;
    }

    function getAbility(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.ability;
    }

    function getMoves(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.moves;
    }

    function getHeight(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.height;
    }

    function getWeight(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        PokemonInfo memory c = pokemonList[tokenId];
        return c.weight;
    }

    function getTokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            "{",
            '"name": "Generate Random Pokemon #',
            tokenId.toString(),
            '",',
            '"description": "Generate Random Pokemon",',
            '"image": "',
            generateCharacter(tokenId),
            '"',
            "}"
        );
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:application/json;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(dataURI)
                )
            );
    }

    function mint() private {
        uint256 newItemId = _nextTokenId;
        require(newItemId < MAX_SUPPLY, "All tokens have already been minted");
        _nextTokenId++; // Increment after minting
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, getTokenURI(newItemId));
    }

    function generatePokeMon(
        string calldata name,
        string calldata height,
        string calldata weight,
        string calldata moves,
        string calldata ability
    ) public {
        pokemonList.push(PokemonInfo(name, ability, height, weight, moves));
        mint();
    }
}

I tested this by calling the generatePokeMon function on Remix IDE as well as on Sepolia Etherscan, after verifying the contract available at 0xAf40a3822DF11AAf83a1fd80CbD79B4b8826c45A.
